# Random number within a range but exclude some in Javascript

Tags: javascript, coordinates, intervals, points

I want to create a cloud of points with auto generation. I have no problem with this, I use a random function to create random coordinates.

```
// I used this function twice, for X coordinate and for Y coordinate
// min and max represent width and height intervals
function getRandom(min,max){
    return Math.floor(Math.random()*(max-min+1)+min);
}
```

BUT, I would like to avoid points too close. I thought to push all my points in an array and each time I add a point I compare this one with all others in my array to check distance between them but I'm not sur it's a good idea for performance.

Have you got an idea to do that ? Have you got some scripts or others ressources to help me ?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Performance may or may not matter.  How many points are we talking about?  A few thousand wouldn't be too bad.  Hundreds of thousands would be slow.

Comment: You could always split that range into smaller ranges so there are fewer comparisons to make or maybe ranges that would erase the need for comparisons such as getRandom( 1, 5 ); getRandom( 6, 10 ); getRandom( 11, 15 ); getRandom( 16, 20 ); rather than four+ calls to getRandom( 1, 20 ); with spacing. If that's still too close, maybe adjust the min based on the previously found value.

Comment: If you put a correlation between the points, i.e. not allowing to be too close from each other, these are no more random. Perhaps another approach is to decide how many points a square is allowed to receive. Since the density of points over your domain will be more or less constant, you will be able to compute how many points you will be allowed to scatter randomly over your domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you use `Math.floor`, I would assume they are pixel, perhaps voxel coordinates. In this case you can also store the entire rectangle/brick in an array and just "disable" the vicinity of already selected locations by drawing a disc/sphere around them.

Mockup with canvas:

```js
function magic(){
    var cnv=document.getElementById("cnv");
    var ctx=cnv.getContext("2d");
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,cnv.width,cnv.height);
    ctx.fillStyle="#D0D0D0";
    ctx.strokeStyle="#000000";
    var numdots=parseInt(document.getElementById("numdots").value);
    var mindist=parseInt(document.getElementById("mindist").value);
    var tries=0;
    for(var i=0;i<numdots;i++){
        var retry=true;
        while(retry){
            tries++;
            var x=Math.random()*cnv.width;
            var y=Math.random()*cnv.height;
            retry=ctx.getImageData(x,y,1,1).data[0]!==0;
        }
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(x,y,mindist-2,0,Math.PI*2);
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(x,y,1,0,Math.PI*2);
        ctx.stroke();
    }
    document.getElementById("log").innerHTML=tries;
}
magic();
```

```html
<input type="number" id="numdots" value="100">
<input type="number" id="mindist" value="20">
<button onclick="magic()">Do</button>
<span id="log"></span><br>
<canvas id="cnv" width="300" height="300"></canvas>
```

(The first number is the number of points you want to place, the second one is the minimum distance you want to keep between them, and the one appearing at the end is the number of tries it has taken to place all the points)

This one is short and slow, both because using canvas and imagedata. With a simple typedarray and an own implementation of [circle drawing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midpoint_circle_algorithm#JavaScript) it could be faster and longer.